# How to share transactions between multiple threads

Tags: java, transactions, jta

I have a configured nirayana standalone JTA and two REST endpoints

1. for beginning a transaction
2. using transaction

   ```
   @GetMapping("/starttx")  
   public String starttx() throws NotSupportedException, SystemException  
   {  
   //        TransactionManager transactionManager = com.arjuna.ats.jta.TransactionManager.transactionManager();  
       UserTransaction userTransaction = com.arjuna.ats.jta.UserTransaction.userTransaction();  
       System.out.println(userTransaction);  
       userTransaction.begin();  
       System.out.println(userTransaction.getStatus());  
       System.out.println("trx started");  
       return "started";  
   }  

   @GetMapping("/createAccount")  
   // @Transactional(rollbackFor=RuntimeException.class)  
   public String account() throws SystemException  
   {  

       UserTransaction userTransaction = com.arjuna.ats.jta.UserTransaction.userTransaction();  
       System.out.println(userTransaction.getStatus());  

       em.persist(new AccountEntity("acc1"));  
       return "created account";  
   }
   ```

I call starttrx and createAccount respectively but in createAccount transaction status is 6 which means it is not active how can I share transaction which is created in starttx endpoint with createAccount ?

Comment: It is unusual approach. Most application use new transaction per rest request. In your case you have to manage transaction manually, `@Transactional` won't work in this case.

Comment: not so unusual if you face this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54745015/how-to-rollback-distributed-transactions

Comment: Those cases are unrelated, solution for refereed question is some sort of distributed transaction manager (which is also far from common practice). This question requires explicit control over beginning of transaction available to client code (in all the cases I can imagine there is better solution) .